# .htaccess redirect rule default index and remove .php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

Hi am a bit slow when it comes to htaccess and this has been giving me a headache all day. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but all my combos of attempts to fix this go awry.

I want index.php to be set as the default index page for folders and the homepage of the site to redirect to formacompany.com/en I don't want .php on the end of my files.

Here is my code i want www.example.com/ru to display the index.php file in the directory but don't want the url to be www.example.com/ru/index

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

redirect 301 /admin/ http://www.example.com/_admin/index.php
redirect 301 /payment https://www.example.com/en/secure/ccpayment

redirect 301 http://www.formacompany.com http://www.formacompany.com/en/index
```

when i visit example.com/ru i get this as the url and a page error:

http://www.example.com/ru/index//index//index//index//index//index//index//index//index//index//index//index//index//index//index//index//index//index//index//index//

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `mod_rewrite` rules with `mod_alias` ones and keep redirect rules before internal rewrite ones:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php 

RewriteEngine On   

RewriteRule ^admin/?$ http://www.example.com/_admin/index.php [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^payment/?$ https://www.example.com/en/secure/ccpayment [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.formacompany.com/en/index [L,R=302]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```